# SearchView is taking extra space in bottom and also not remove another icon available on ActionBar. Search Icon is available on Activity Action Bar

Tags: android, searchview

Bottom of Search is taking more space.

[image]

Comment: Use [Show layout bounds](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGqJhK0FTjw) to analyze what view is occupying how much size of screen.

Comment: try setting background to searchview and identify how much space it is occupying.